# Query to join same table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table looking like the following:

```
Key1    key2    Value      Key          Online
a       1       "AMAZON"   "STORE"       True
a       1       10         "AMOUNT"     True
a       1       10:00:00   "HOUR"       False
a       2       "NIKE"     "STORE"      False
a       2       5          "AMOUNT"     False
```

If I would like to make a query that would return me for a given key1+key2 the value for the key "STORE" + the value for the key "AMOUNT" what should I do?

I would like in this case to get the following result:

```
key1   key2       store     amount
a      1          "amazon"  10
a      2          "nike"    5
```

Comment: Is really  hard to follow... What have you tried? Where do you get your variables?

Comment: In your sample desired result, key1 and key2 are not the same, which contradicts the question as formulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish the result you want is to use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
  key1, 
  key2, 
  max(case when `key`='STORE'  then `value` end) store,
  max(case when `key`='AMOUNT' then `value` end) amount
from table1
group by key1, key2;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e67c7a/3)

Also, `key` is a reserved word that needs to be enclosed in back-ticks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get what you show in the result table, you just need to do:

```
SELECT key1, key2, 
    (SELECT LOWER(value) FROM table WHERE key = 'STORE') AS store, 
    (SELECT value FROM table WHERE key = 'AMOUNT')) AS amount
FROM table
GROUP BY key1, key2;
```